# C programming on Ubuntu

Tags: programming, libraries, gcc, c

I have problems related to C programming on Ubuntu 12.04. While compiling C program consisting `pow` I faced difficulties. Then I searched the Internet and got the solution with `-lm`. But that's the compiling part. How to execute and Run that program that has `pow` in it? I failed to execute and run.  The message said `No such file or directory`. What can I do?

Again, is there any easy way of learning C programming on Ubuntu, where I can fully concentrate on coding? I prefer not to have to think about compiling, executing and running the code. Should I use an IDE for that? What do you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem using the function `pow` is that it's a function from another library, not from the C language. So, you need to link to the `math` library. But I don't get why you can't run the program. What complete command are you using to compile and what to run?

About using an IDE, I recommend you not to use it while you're learning, or you can miss the understanding of how everything works.

Comment: "gcc -Wall 13.c -o 13.out -lm"                                   "chmod +x 13"                                                    "./13" These are the codes I used for compiling, executing and running my code. It compiled I think, but failed to execute and run. The message says 'No such file or directory'.

Comment: You should do "chmod +x 13.out", no? and execute "./13.out"

Answer (score 0):

As you are about to use the `math.h` header file.
In terminal:

```
cd /your/directory/name
cc your_program.c -lm
```

I think this helps you.